# What are the privileges and duties of assigning a gold badge in a tag?

Tags: discussion, badges, privileges

I just got a gold badge for the `pgf-tikz` tag. I know that this badge gives me the privilege of closing with my vote alone a question with this tag if I feel that it is duplicated.
This golden badge is a privilege and therefore also a responsibility.
Some holders of this badge say that they no longer vote to close or open questions on their gold badges.

- Are there other privileges that gold badges give?
- What attitude have you decided to adopt since you acquired a gold badge?

Comment: congratulations on the badge:-) I don't not use the close vote; sometimes it makes sense just to close obvious duplicates, but in more marginal cases (the typical, "not really a a duplicate but could be considered one as same technique needed for the answer") I am more likely to just comment with a link to the older question, to give others chance to vote.  As far as I can see that is in practice the only difference having the badge makes  (and I think a similar but less used power to re-open closed ones)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. Your way of doing things seems very reasonable to me and I think I'll do as you do unless someone else is more persuasive.

Comment: Besides closing you can also instantly reopen closed questions in the tag, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836/.

Comment: @Marijn Yes, indeed, it is surprising that this information is not even specified in the help center!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tag score of 1,000 on a minimum of 200 answers shows that you have a huge experience in that field. The golden tag badge shows that, and it shows the trust in your expertise. This trust comes with the privileges to

- instantly close a question as a duplicate
- instantly reopen a question closed as a duplicate

that has that tag, with the condition that the question author originally used that tag. (Adding a tag and then using the tag privilege would not work, for logical reasons).

There's no duty involved having by a tag badge: we are here voluntarily. And as you said: another privilege is just another thing we use responsibly.